# While loop doesnt run correctly because of string

Tags: c++

when I call this function to my while loop in main, the second time the while loop runs the part to enter the client name is already filled with the name that was input by the user the first time. how could I avoid this.

```
void u_input(double &pr, string &nacl)
{
    cout<<"Enter the name of the client: "<<nacl;
    getline(cin, nacl);
    cout<<"How much is the sale price of the house";
    cin>>pr;
}
```

`

Comment: You avoid this by not storing the input in the same variable you are using for output.

Comment: or just don't do `<<nacl` at the end of your prompt line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way to avoid it is to simply not print it when you ask for a new name!

```
void u_input(double &pr, string &nacl)
{
    cout<<"Enter the name of the client: ";
    getline(cin, nacl);
    cout<<"How much is the sale price of the house";
    cin>>pr;
}
```

Another easy option is to call `nacl.clear()` at the start of the `u_input` function. The `clear()` member function erases the contents of the string (but maintains the existing capacity).

Comment: Tried both ways, but the second time it skips running the enter the name of the client line. it goes to the how much is the sale price immediately

Answer (score 0):

I' not sure how long the rest of your program is but am gonna give it a shot

you can keep the variables to store the user information in main and build an array for the two variable so you can input as much information as you..
am kinda of a newbie but i hope that just gives you a general idea.

the information you put will be deleted though when ever u start the program again XD

```
    loopControl = 1;
    char answer;

    string clientName[10];
    float price[10];
    int i = 0;

    while(loopControl =0)
    { 
     void u_input();
     cin >> clientName[i]; 
     cin >> price[i];

    i++;

    cout << "would u like to enter more information?   y/n" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if ( answer = 'y')
       loopControl = 0;

    else 
       loopControl = 1

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Below can do it for you:

```
void u_input(double &pr,string &nacl)
{
    cout<<"Enter the name of the client: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, nacl);
    cout<<"How much is the sale price of the house";
    cin>>pr;
}
```